# How to load cordova.js from a remote website?

Tags: cordova

I know this is a terrible idea, but I have an app that navigates to a website and then loads cordova.js using

```
<script src="cdvfile://localhost/persistent/cordova.js" />
```

But this doesn't seem to work anymore.

Answer (score 1):

There is an defect open, Please check the comment 
 https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/issues/347#issuecomment-545971964

Answer (score 0):

Would you know it... after hours and hours, as soon as I post to StackOverflow, I figured it out.

```
<script src="cdvfile://localhost/bundle/www/cordova.js" />
```

(at least for iOS, can't speak for Android)

Comment: did you ever by chance figure this out for Android?

Comment: This seems to not work for secure websites. for eg. if you have to navigate to "https:" website and then load cordova.js

Answer (score 0):

For android: 
Disable mixed content policy using:
https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW)

For ios: 
I submitted a PR to the file plugin which solves the mixed content problem on ios: apache/cordova-plugin-file#296
The fixed version is available at: https://github.com/guylando/cordova-plugin-file
If you load a remote site https://example.com on the webview then it allows to access local files using the url:
https://example.com/cdvfile/bundle/www/cordova.js
instead of
cdvfile://localhost/bundle/www/cordova.js
And by this solves the mixed content problems

Comment: Could you share the code to implement the android side?

Comment: @syonip created a private cordova plugin and used there similar code to the one here https://github.com/ionic-team/cordova-plugin-ionic-webview/issues/231 to disable view mixed content on plugin load and configured the cordova plugin to load on app load

Comment: Thanks Guy. I've implemented a different way of doing this as I didn't want to change security settings in the webview, see here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/56363629/2942294

Comment: @syonip since the hosted website is your website, if a malicious content will be included in it then you have bigger problems than those created by disabling the mixed content policy. Thus I do no believe you improve your security in this specific case unless you can describe a scenario where the mixed content protection in cordova hosted website controller by you will save you. An attacker injecting malicious content will always be able to host https content if needed.

Comment: Hmmm I will have to think about a scenario :)