# Cordova In app browser App Transport Security

Tags: ios, cordova, http, inappbrowser, app-transport-security

I am trying to load content in an In App Browser from my local server ( using httpd plugin ). the web page is coming from a https, while the local server is loading of course a http.

I am testing on an Iphone x IOS 12. Using adobe Build

Tried:

```
<access origin='*' allows-arbitrary-loads-in-media='true' allows-arbitrary-loads-in-web-content='true' allows-local-networking='true' />

<edit-config target="NSAllowsArbitraryLoads" file="*-Info.plist" mode="merge">

<true />

</edit-config>

<plugin name="cordova-plugin-transport-security" source="npm" />
```

Error:

```
[blocked] The page at https://somewebpage was not allowed to run insecure content from http://127.0.0.1:8080/javascripts/somejsfile.js.
```

none of these worked. anyone have a suggestion?

Answer (score 3):

This is not an App transport security problem, its a mixed content policy violation.
Solution:

For android: Disable mixed content policy by putting the following code inside the pluginInitialize method of your cordova plugin:

```
if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= android.os.Build.VERSION_CODES.LOLLIPOP) {
            final WebSettings settings = ((WebView)this.webView.getView()).getSettings();
      settings.setMixedContentMode(WebSettings.MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW);
        }
```

https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebSettings.html#MIXED_CONTENT_ALWAYS_ALLOW)

Then include local cordova.js using:

```
<script src="cdvfile://localhost/assets/www/cordova.js"></script>
```

For ios: I submitted a PR to the file plugin which solves the mixed content problem on ios: apache/cordova-plugin-file#296 The fixed version is available at: https://github.com/guylando/cordova-plugin-file If you load a remote site https://example.com on the webview then it allows to access local files using the url: https://example.com/cdvfile/bundle/www/cordova.js instead of cdvfile://localhost/bundle/www/cordova.js And by this solves the mixed content problems

Include local cordova.js using:

```
<script src="/cdvfile/bundle/www/cordova.js"></script>
```

Comment: This looks like a good solution, i will give it a shot, thanks!

Comment: Actually it doesnt seem to work, am i missing something? i included your version of the file plugin, withen my in app browser i included a js resource `https://myhosturl/cdvfile/bundle/www/cordova.js` for example and it came back with 404 not found.

Comment: @Keenan35i this is the tag I include which works: <script src="/cdvfile/bundle/www/cordova.js"></script>

Comment: Also this is for ios only. For android after disabling mixed content policy use: <script src="cdvfile://localhost/assets/www/cordova.js"></script>
notice "assets" instead of "bundle"

Comment: I use it inside the cordova UIWebView which is navigated to the remote url. I didn't use it from inappbrowser plugin.

Comment: If it still doesnt work on ios please open the file CDVFile.m in xcode and put a breakpoint in the canInitWithRequest method to see why this url isn't handled by the plugin

Comment: im also using wkwebview plugin, that may be an issue as well no?

Comment: WKWebView prevents access to local files but this can be enabled using allowFileAccessFromFileURLs option of the view, see: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35554814/wkwebview-xmlhttprequest-with-file-url

Comment: put a breakpoint where I said and it will help understand if the code flow reaches the file handling or not and will help understand where is the problem instead of guessing

Answer (score 2):

Another solution for android that doesn't change the security settings of the browser, is to use `"https://cdvfile/assets/www/cordova.js"` instead of `"cdvfile://localhost/assets/www/cordova.js"`, and add the following line to the `remapUri` method in `FileUtils.java` (in the cordova file plugin):

```
uri = Uri.parse(uri.toString().replace("https://cdvfile/", "cdvfile://localhost/"));
```

This will load the file as usual and not cause the webview to block the request.

See PR https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-file/pull/322